# Can there be multiple eventloop threads for Netty UDP server?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I'm trying to build a UDP server based on Netty to continuously publish events (about 500 events per second) to different clients based on client subscription (a few UDP request/response messages are exchanged before a subscription setup).

The design is to have a few producer/consumer threads created by Java Executors. Once a messages is generated, consumer threads will write it to the UDP channel.

The observation is there's only one EventLoop thread working for that UDP channel in server end, and it is quite busy with writing messages to socket, so the response to the 2nd and later client's subscription request is quite slow.

So wondering if any way to enable multiple worker threads for NIO UDP server end, so that one or a few threads busy with writing publishing events to socket, we still have other threads to process new client subscription requests without delay. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

btw, server-side Netty handlers are quite simple: a logging handler, a decoder hander, a encoder handler, and a subscription handler.

Comment: Could you show me your code？Maybe you can set    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
    .group(new NioEventLoopGroup(N));  to create N  threads.

Comment: Thanks @mattia. Here's the code snipper - `code` Bootstrap udpBoot = new Bootstrap(); udpBoot.group(new NioEventLoopGroup(10).channel(NioDatagramChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true).option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true).handler(new ChannelInitializer<Datagram>(){ @Override protected void initChannel(DatagramChannel ch) throws Exception {ch.pipeline().addLast(loggingHandler).addLast(new MyDatagramToPojoDecoder(adapter)).addLast(new MyPojoToDatagramEncoder(adapter)).addLast(new MySessionHandler(service)).addLast(new MySubscriptionHandler(service));}});`code`

Comment: I guess Netty is allocating EventLoop threads to different channels, however in UDP, there's only one channel, this way only eventloop thread is working.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer in general no... As a `Channel` is always tied to one `EventLoop` there will only be one Thread handling it. That said if you use the native epoll transport (which only works on linux) you can use `EpollChannelOption.SO_REUSEPORT` to bind multiple `Channel`s to the same port which are handled by different `EventLoop`s and so `Thread`s.

Comment: thanks. But noted the statement "It is also important to note that this solution works well for datagrams received from different remote transport addresses. The SO_REUSEPORT option is implemented by the kernel and will dispatch received datagrams to the created sockets based on the source transport address." [http://marrachem.blogspot.jp/2014/09/multi-threaded-udp-server-with-netty-on.html]. However, this is exactly our case that we have to publish lot of messages every milliseconds to a single client.